# How to locate trash directory containing files deleted from php application on ubuntu

Tags: server, trash

Need to locate the trash directory where deleted files from a php application are stored.

Can anyone help with the trash directory on an ubuntu server machine online?

Comment: Trash : `/home/[name]/.local/share/Trash/` . ............... But if files are deleted, they are not "stored".

Comment: If the PHP application is using `unlink()` to delete files, then there is no *simple* means of recovery. If the PHP application is temporarily moving the files to a different location (like NextCloud does) before deleting at a later date, then you will need to check the source code to determine where in the application directory files are placed.

Comment: The question seems unanswerable since any answer is application-dependent...we don't know which application you are looking at. Ubuntu Server has no systemwide nor user-level Trash directory. Deleted files are simply gone (subject to uncertain and laborious data recovery)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one. Deleted files are gone. If you want them back you'll have to restore them from your backup.